# Is there a sequence point between structure member initializations?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sequence-points

Is there a sequence point between structure member initialization expressions?

For example, is it well defined that the code bellow will always print "a, b"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char *bytes;
    int position;
    int length;
} Stream;

typedef struct {
    char a;
    char b;
} Pair;

char streamgetc(Stream *stream) {
    return (stream->position < stream->length) ? stream->bytes[stream->position++] : 0;
}

int main(void) {
    Stream stream = {.bytes = "abc", .position = 0, .length = 3};
    Pair pair = {.a = streamgetc(&stream), .b = streamgetc(&stream)};
    printf("%c, %c\n", pair.a, pair.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `§6.7.8-23` settles it:

> The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list
>   expressions is unspeciﬁed.

And about compound literals:

> `§6.5.2.5-7`
>
> All the semantic rules and constraints for initializer lists in 6.7.8
>   are applicable to compound literals.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the relevant wording in C99 TC2 (n1124) is in §6.7.8/23:

> The order in which any side effects occur among the initialization list expressions is
>   unspecified<sup>131</sup>.

The footnote says:

> 131) In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization.

Comment: I liked (and up voted for) the addition of footnote 131, but I went with the older answer because I thought both were complete.

Comment: Does that mean that the evaluation of the expressions associated with different elements is guaranteed not to overlap, but that any number of such expressions may be evaluated between the time any particular one is evaluated and the corresponding structure element is actually written?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can see for yourself in Annex C of the C standard (or drafts n1256, n1516, etc.).

There is a sequence point after each *full* declarator, and there will still be sequence points from expressions inside the initialization that use `&&` or call functions.

There isn't a sequence point between function arguments either.

```
func(getc(), getc()); // who knows what order?
```